# Show MySQL URL properties

Tags: java, mysql-connector

MySQL have many properties, which I can set in url: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

But is there any select command with which I can look at the current values of the parameters on the server? For example, How I can show current value of variable `allowMultiQueries`?

For examle: `SELECT .... WHERE .... like %allowMultiQueries%` or or something similar.

Comment: These are settings for the java MySQL client "Connector/J", not for the MySQL server or is part of SQL. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I try connect to MySQL using JDBC. My url look like this: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:32803/test?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&allowMultiQueries=true`. In test I want to check, that the property `allowMultiQueries` successfully set to true.

Comment: What information do you get when you use [`getClientInfo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getClientInfo()) on the Connection object?

Comment: Nothing. I get this in debug in my ide: clientInfo= {Properties@4482} size = 0